# Set raw resource as ringtone in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-mediaplayer, android-contentresolver, mediastore

In my android application, I want to set audio file from my `raw` folder as a ringtone.
For that i wrote below code, but its not working.

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Code :

```
String name =best_song_ever.mp3;
File newSoundFile = new File("/sdcard/media/ringtone",
                        "myringtone.mp3");
                Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                        + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + name);
                ContentResolver mCr = context.getContentResolver();
                AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
                try {
                    soundFile = mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    soundFile = null;
                }

            try {
                byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
                FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
                int i = fis.read(readData);

                while (i != -1) {
                    fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                    i = fis.read(readData);
                }

                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException io) {
            }
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                    newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "my ringtone");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/oog");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media
                    .getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

            try {
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
            } catch (Throwable t) {

            }

            Toast.makeText(context, name + " is set as ringtone.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code solved my problem:

```cs
String name = "your_raw_audio_name";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/myRingtonFolder/Audio/");
if (!file.exists()) {
   file.mkdirs();
}

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
   .getAbsolutePath() + "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/";
File f = new File(path + "/", name + ".mp3");
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                    + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + name);
ContentResolver mCr = context.getContentResolver();
AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
try {
    soundFile = mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    soundFile = null;
}

try {
    byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
    FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    int i = fis.read(readData);
    while (i != -1) {
        fos.write(readData, 0, i);
        i = fis.read(readData);
    }
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException io) {}

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, f.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, name);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, f.length());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

try {
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
        RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
    Settings.System.putString(mCr, Settings.System.RINGTONE,newUri.toString());
} catch (Throwable t) {}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at context.getContentResolver(); what am I supposed to set it to exactly?

Comment: With this code we are creating a new file in the device using the raw audio file? Is it like extracting the audio? There is no another way to achive it?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to set the same res as ringtone again, the below modification might be helpful

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(f
                     .getAbsolutePath());
mCr.delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i used: very usefull to me:)

```
    String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 String path=(exStoragePath +"/media/alarms/"); 

    saveas(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename+".mp3"
          + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); 




 File k = new File(path, filename);

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path + filename  );
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,  filename );
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");

//new
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);  

// Insert it into the database
this.getContentResolver()
.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
  .getAbsolutePath()), values);
```

Or refer on this complete [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/09/set-raw-resource-file-as-ringtone-in.html)

HAPPY CODING!