# Android - How to set song as ringtone or notification from raw folder?

Tags: android, listview, audio, ringtone

I have a listview with sounds items. I need, when a item is long press es,  set it as ringtone or notification from raw sound of my app. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: So nothing solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from my other post here...

[Set ringtone from res/raw folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645511/set-ringtone-from-res-raw-folder/22645920#22645920)

You cannot set the ringtone from resource.

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri expects the ringtone file in the device and the Uri should be from content resolver.

```
    File ring = new File("pathOfYourFile");
     Uri path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ring.getAbsolutePath());
```

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,path);

Also make sure to add permission