# set as default ringtone from raw folder programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-file

**I tried this code its working fine to load the sound file to ringtones directory.I can manually select the sound from popup ..but its fail to set as default ringtone programmatically.plz help me to set the sound as default ringtone programmatically**

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
     path=(exStoragePath +"/media/alarms/");
            // saveas();
        saveas(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

    }

    // In this method, we need to copy the mp3 file to the sd card location from
    // where android picks up ringtone files
    // After copying, we make the mp3 as current ringtone
public boolean saveas(int type) {
enter code here
    byte[] buffer = null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.sound);
    int size = 0;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }


    String filename = "sound";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        return false;

    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename + ".mp3"
            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
enter code here
    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path + filename  );
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,  filename );
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");

    //new
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,this.getContentResolver()
    .insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
            .getAbsolutePath()), values));



    return true;

}
```

Comment: What is the point of passing the RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE if it's never used in saveas(int type)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this code 
`RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,this.getContentResolver()
    .insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
            .getAbsolutePath()), values));`

and put  these lines code before return true and its work

```
 Uri newUri = this.getContentResolver()
            .insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
                    .getAbsolutePath()), values);
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 try {
                Uri notification = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.phone_funny_bell);
                Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                r.play();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        r.stop();
                    }
                }, 3000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Use this one. This will work.**

place above code on **MyFirebaseMessagingService** inside this **onMessageReceived**